# Optimising for O_DIRECT writes

Tags: c++, c, linux, io

I'm trying to write an application which will need to write to disk very quickly. I've hit my performance target for writing to disk, which is great.

However, I've noticed that writing to disk so quickly is using a lot of CPU time: One core is maxed out, another is at 80% and another 2 are 10-20%. So I heard that O_DIRECT can decrease CPU consumption by avoiding all of those copies into kernel space and then copies to disk.

I ran a small test program which confirmed this - CPU usage drops to 50% of one core - much better.

However, I never got quite the same throughput as I did when doing normal writes and to make it quick, I had to use a *really* big record size (something like 130MB!)

So, the question is, I guess:

- Is there a better way to decrease CPU usage than O_DIRECT for writes?
  or
- How can I get a similar throughput to what the kernel gets?

My enviroment is Linux, I'm using a RAID 50, and I'm able to buffer writes until I hit some optimal record size. There will be only one writer at a time.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting [this page](http://kerneltrap.org/node/7563):

> With O_DIRECT the kernel will do DMA directly from/to the physical memory pointed [to] by the userspace buffer passed as [a] parameter to the read/write syscalls. So there will be no CPU and memory bandwidth spent in the copies between userspace memory and kernel cache, and there will be no CPU time spent in kernel in the management of the cache (like cache lookups, per-page locks etc..).

Basically you are trading throughput for CPU performance when using `O_DIRECT`. The kernel stops optimizing the throughput for you, and in return you get predictable results and full control.

Long story short: with `O_DIRECT` you'll have to do the caching and other optimizing yourself which increase throughput. The huge record size doesn't seem so weird now.

I'm not aware of any other methods, but I'm not a linux guru. Feel free to ask around :)

Comment: Thanks nightcracker. I guess what I was asking, is what optimisations does the kernel do? Because presumably, I can duplicate that to get a similar throughput the kernel acheives - that or take a better approach. Looking at disk I/O stats, it doesn't look like the kernel buffers upwars of 100MBs before it writes

Comment: I'm not a linux guru and I'm only 16 :) My guesses would be caching and buffering (maybe with a dynamic buffer that doubles in size after every write). I would suggest that you just look at the linux kernel source code, but I wouldn't know where you should start looking. Sorry, I'm not very helpful in this case :)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to somehow arrange for more I/O to be kept in flight at the same time AND submit them down at the optimal size. When the kernel buffers your write I/Os together there are number of benefit that can happen:

- It may become possible to merge contiguous I/Os together into bigger I/Os. If so there's an opportunity to save overhead because rather than submitting 8 small 4KBytes I/Os down the kernel is now able to submit 1 64Kbyte I/O down (for example).
- It opens up a parallel submission possibility. If the kernel is able to batch up 256k it may now be able to send that down as 8 simultaneous I/Os thus achieving a higher iodepth.

So

> Is there a better way to decrease CPU usage than O_DIRECT for writes?

Yes send bigger I/Os up to the optimal size prefered by your disk.

> How can I get a similar throughput to what the kernel gets?

Ideally do the above (send optimally sized I/Os) and ensure the maximum I/Os that your disk likes are kept in-flight at once (e.g. by submitting asynchronously or via multiple threads/processes if you're going to use blocking routines) and submit the I/Os in the disk's LBA order. A slightly less optimal trick is to send huge I/Os down and force the kernel to split them to create parallelism but this less optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `mmap` and `msync`? I don't know if it is faster or less CPU intensive, but as it represent a whole other approach to I/O (basically it's the kernel that does the I/O for you) it can be an interesting venue.

Comment: I just gave mmap and msync a go - I seem to get a similar story to O_DIRECT - better efficiency as I crank up to a very large record size, but otherwise, poor performance. Thanks for the suggestion.