# setting using_dma to 1 (on) - fails

Tags: io, c++

**Situation**

For one of my projects I want to bypass almost all io caches. Therefore I'm using the flag `O_DIRECT` to access my hdd. The program code looks similar to this:

```
 int fd = open64("/dev/sdb", O_DIRECT  | O_RDWR |  O_LARGEFILE |  O_SYNC);
```

- `O_DIRECT` - bypasses almost all caches
- `O_RDWR` - Read write Permissions
- `O_SYNC` - Synch. writing

The general program is that I'm not able to access the HDD with the flag `O_DIRECT`. Therefore I did some research and found out that [DMA has to be activated.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814952/optimising-for-o-direct-writes)

This can be done using the following command:

```
(sudo) hdparm -d1 /dev/sdb
```

The result is:

```
/dev/sdb:
setting using_dma to 1 (on)
HDIO_SET_DMA failed: Invalid argument
HDIO_GET_DMA failed: Invalid argument
```

**Question**

How do I enable DMA for a local HDD?